# Apple login in android with FireBase Auth has problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-login

Google account's grade is spark.

Firebase project has two platforms, android and ios.

First, download google-services.json and move to /app.

Second, I create Apple Service Id and configure domains as '`fb-projectid`.firebaseapp.com'

and return urls as 'https://`fb-projectid`.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler' copy from Firebase Authentication - Sign-in Method - apple.

Third, make Apple Private Key with Grouped App Id.

Fourth, copy Key ID + Key file content and paste to Firebase Authentication - Sign-in Method - apple - OAuth code flow configuration.

In android app, I set button's setOnClickListener()

```
fun appleLogin(activity : FragmentActivity) {
    val provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("apple.com")
    provider.scopes = arrayOf("email", "name").toMutableList()
    provider.addCustomParameter("locale", "ko_KR")

    auth = Firebase.auth

    val pending = auth.pendingAuthResult
    if (pending != null) {
        pending.addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
            Log.d(MyApp.tag, "checkPending:onSuccess:$authResult")
            // Get the user profile with authResult.getUser() and
            // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo(), and the ID
            // token from Apple with authResult.getCredential().
        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.w(MyApp.tag, "checkPending:onFailure", e)
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(MyApp.tag, "pending: null")
        auth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(activity, provider.build())
                .addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->
                    // Sign-in successful!
                    Log.d(MyApp.tag, "activitySignIn:onSuccess:${authResult.user}")
                    val user = authResult.user
                    // ...
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.w(MyApp.tag, "activitySignIn:onFailure", e)
                }
    }
}
```

But I got an error

`activitySignIn:onFailure com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash. [ Client does not match API key ]`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your SHA-1 key to the Firebase project.

Open your app in Firebase-> Settings -> General -> SDK setup and configuration -> Add fingerprint.

Comment: thank you. In project, We decided not to add the function, hhhhh